# Foreach loop don't show fetch data from database correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I have two tables in the database (details and image) and I fetch the first table correctly(details).details has a row with name is code and I want to fetch the image table with the code element that comes in the details table.

the table details are like  this :

```
$response = array();

$sql = " SELECT * FROM `details` ORDER BY `id` DESC ";
$run = $connect->prepare($sql);
$run->execute();
$record = $run->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$response['res'] =[$record];
echo json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

and the response is like this:

```
{
    "res": [
        [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "bucher",
                "name": "jack sib",
                "start": "7am to 6pm",
                "details": "gtgtty rtrtrt",
                "user": "example@yahoo.com",
                "code": "ulv1mx8wztcyvf55ns4hlcgr11lzktyh",
                "time": "2020-08-21 16:24:19"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "super market",
                "name": "alibaba",
                "start": "6 Am to 6 Pm",
                "details": "everything is good and get better",
                "user": "example2@yahoo.com",
                "code": "umtyw95hu4voe49rz95ej0cftmnglom1",
                "time": "2020-08-17 17:26:40"
            }
}
```

and everything is good and correct, but when i want to fetch image from database and i want to show every image with the special code but it just show me one image with the code.

i write code fething image like this:

```
foreach ($record as $row){
        $sqlImage = " SELECT * FROM `image` WHERE code= ? LIMIT 1 ";
        $runImage = $connect->prepare($sqlImage);
        $runImage->bindValue(1, $row['code']);
        $runImage->execute();
        $recordImage = $runImage->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

and the response is :

```
{
    "advert": [
        [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "bucher",
                "name": "jack sib",
                "start": "7am to 6pm",
                "details": "gtgtty rtrtrt",
                "user": "example@yahoo.com",
                "code": "ulv1mx8wztcyvf55ns4hlcgr11lzktyh",
                "time": "2020-08-21 16:24:19"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "title": "super market",
                "name": "alibaba",
                "start": "6 Am to 6 Pm",
                "details": "everything is good and get better",
                "user": "example2@yahoo.com",
                "code": "umtyw95hu4voe49rz95ej0cftmnglom1",
                "time": "2020-08-17 17:26:40"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "user": "example2@yahoo.com",
                "url": "..\/public\/uploadPic\/cb49f60092bb9b28e69487171208a0d09.jpg",
                "token": "umtyw95hu4voe49rz95ej0cftmnglom1"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

and the second image is not displayinag and i don't know why.

Comment: Using `JOIN` will fetch you everything in 1 query.

Comment: Don't do queries in a loop. Databases do that sort of thing significantly well already.

Comment: how?? could you please rewrite the code?

Comment: I imagine the sql query should look something like `SELECT details.*, image.url, image.token FROM details JOIN image ON details.code = image.code ORDER BY details.id DESC`

Comment: Your image query says `LIMIT 1`, which limits it to 1 result. If you want more than one result, don't use `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably fetch the wanted results in a single query, including the image if exists for the specific code. Otherwise, it will return `NULL` in the `image` table columns.

```
SELECT details.*, image.* FROM details LEFT JOIN details 
ON image.code = details.code ORDER BY details.id DESC
```

Please be aware that you're pulling out all data from `image` table, which seems unnecessary as you already have the code from the first table and only need the image URL and token.

You can rewrite the query to only append the image from the second table:

```
SELECT details.*, image.url, image.token FROM details LEFT JOIN details 
ON image.code = details.code ORDER BY details.id DESC
```

Comment: this is a good way, but i want to fetch all of elements of image tables. for example in my problem there are two row of image but when i put them in foreach to fetch both of them but just one of them appeare.

Comment: I have two token in details table and i want to can see all of image element in image table with special token according token of details table.